# login autorization error getting Undefined variable: erros

Tags: php, laravel

I'm start learning laravel and want to create sample login authorization system on my html template. I watched a tutorial and when i do everything that was in video i get error `Undefined variable: erros`.
I'm new and I don't know good PHP but i want to learn while creating a website I know a little.

my rout code is my route code :

this is route for my login code

```
Route::get ('/main', 'MainController@index');
Route::get ('/main/checklogin', 'MainController@checklogin');
Route::get ('/main/successlogin', 'MainController@successlogin');
Route::get ('/main/logout', 'MainController@logout');
```

1.my login code

```
    <div class="login slide-up">
        <div class="center">

            <h2 class="form-title" id="login"><span>sign</span>in</h2>
             @if (isset(Auth::user()->email))
            <script>window.location="/main/successlogin"</script>
            @endif 

            @if ($message = Session::get('error'))
            <div class ="alert alert-danger alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">X</button>
            <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
            @endif
            <form method="get" action="{{   url('/main/checklogin')
            }}">
            @if(count($errors)  >0 )
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
            @foreach($erros->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
            <form method="get" action="{{   url('/main/checklogin')
            }}">
            {{ csrf_field()}} 
            <div class="form-holder">
                <input type="email" class="input" placeholder="email" />
                <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
            <button class="submit-btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>
```

2.my successlogin code

```
<html>
<body>

@if (issets(auth::user()->email))
<p>gamarjoba {{Auth::user()->email}}}</p>
<a href="{{ url('/main/logout') }}" > logout </a>

else

<script>windows.location = "/main";   </script>

@endif

</body>
</html>
```

my main controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {

    return view('front/login');

    }

    function checklogin(Request $request)

    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'         =>  'required|email',
            'password'       =>  'required|alphaNum|min:4'
        ]);
            $user_data = array(

                'email'         => $request -> get('email'),
                'password'      => $request -> get('password')
            );

            if (Auth::attempt($user_data))
            {

                return redirect('main/successlogin');

            }
            else
            {

            return back()->with('error', 'wrong Login Details');

            }

    }

    function successlogin()
    {

        return view('successlogin');

    }


    function logout()
    {

        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('main');
    }

}
```

Comment: no where in your code is `$erros` defined

Comment: Where do you define `$errors` and `$erros` I also would avoid having variables with such similiar names, assuming that isnt a typo.

Comment: In your successlogin `@if (issets(auth::user()->email))`, It's `isset()`.

Comment: You have so many typo in your code. One error is also here, and I think this is where you are getting  `undefined error` 
`@if(count($errors)  >0 )
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
            @foreach($erros->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach`
It's `$errors->all()`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel made this easy:

Run `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: and it will be fixed?

Comment: C:\laragon\www\cr
λ php artisan make:auth
Authentication scaffolding generated successfully. 

but where its generated?

Comment: That will generate a route, controller and a view for your app login and registration.